# GLControl Doesn't seem to refresh it self more than once

Tags: c#, forms, opengl, opentk

I was using OpenTK.GameWindow class to draw my scene.
Now, I want to use GLControl to draw my scene on it, but the `Paint` Event doesn't have been called more than once!!

I knew that because I'm calling a method to move around in the scene, but actually nothing happens!!

[Event assignment to glControl (Picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JDDK.png)

```
    private void glControl_OnRenderFrame(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        GL.ClearColor(Color.Black);
        GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);

        // Move The Camera ...
        // Draw Stuff ... 

        glControl.SwapBuffers();
    }
```

Comment: Do you call `myControl.Refresh()` after your move-around changes?

Comment: Actually, no I don't.

Comment: Then, try. 'Paint' is triggered automatically in some circumstances.But you can force it when those circumstances are not met.

Comment: Moving the camera is done by the keyboard and the method that responsible for doing that is called in `glControl_OnRenderFrame`, so i need to make it refresh automatically to achieve the desired movement.

Comment: Moving the mouse or using the keyboard will not trigger 'Paint'. Moving a window, changing its size, and some other actions do. Again, try calling Refresh on your own.

Comment: Okay, I will try.